# Different words for "sign"

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

Spanish has several words that could be translated "sign" in English:

- letrero
- rótulo
- señal
- indicio
- cartel
- pancarta
- seña

What are the differences between these words? In what situations can each be used?

Comment: I was thinking of asking exactly this question - I never know which to choose, especially between rótulo and letrero.

Answer (score 5):

```
letrero
```

[image]

```
rótulo
```

[image]

```
señal
```

[image]

```
cartel
```

[image]

```
pancarta
```

[image]

"Indicio" means something like "clue", while "seña" has many meanings, the most usual is "gesture" (like waving a hand, or closing one eye), but also means "a particular characteristic" of someone or something, "a sign made to show a direction or to signal a place", and surprisingly (in some countries/regions) a payment made as a promise to buy (to prevent the seller changing the price or selling to somebody else).

Comment: This is very good, but it would be even better if you could include several examples for each so we can see the semantic range. For instance I'm still having trouble with *rótulo* and *letrero*.

Comment: The photos are great examples, but I'm still curious exactly what each word can refer to. For example, the photos make it look like street signs are always either señal or cartel and not letrero or rótulo?

Comment: @jrdioko There are a lot of local variations. I posted the meanings that I _believe_ are more or less universal.

Comment: @hippie So perhaps [this is more useful than my answer](www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=letrero)

Comment: @belisarius: I believe you need the "http://" to get the link to work right.

Comment: I kind of disagree with the image for rótulo. Rótulo, at least in my country, is a sign with some relief in its letters, usually hand-crafted. I think this one is a better match: http://images.travelpod.com/tripwow/photos/ta-00d1-bcdc-79c8/r%C3%B3tulo-de-espacio-de-teatro-nacional-san-salv-san-salvador-el-salvador+1152_12957484004-tpfil02aw-21651.jpg. "Rotular" is the process of hand-crafting those letters.

Comment: @yms I know there are a lot of local variations. Feel free to edit my answer and add your image! Here "rotular" means just using some (text) sign to identify an object. You could also use "rotular" figuratively as in "That guy is an ...."

Comment: +1 for the banner message.

Comment: @mjuarez It seems you only dreamed about that +1 :D